# Rate limit specific PHP endpoints when running Nginx with php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, rate-limiting, nginx-reverse-proxy

Like many apps, I have some endpoints that are more sensitive than others, such as login & password reset, and need rate limiting. However, nginx handles all requests for PHP resources through a standard location handler that proxies PHP-FPM:

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass php80;
  }
```

This means that I can't also use `location` directives to match my sensitive endpoints as it will prevent them being passed on to PHP.

For example, if I define a rate limit and use it in a location for the login URL:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=sensitive:2m rate=3r/m;
location /login {
    limit_req zone=sensitive burst=3 nodelay;
}
```

It will rate limit the requests to that endpoint, but they will no longer be processed by PHP.

I could do a dumb copy/paste and have this kind of thing for every endpoint:

```
location /login {
    limit_req zone=sensitive burst=3 nodelay;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass php80;
}
```

but I'm sure there's a better way.

How should I define rate limits inside the PHP location directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is move the boilerplate to the server block and just leave `fastcgi_pass` in each `location`. Something like this should work:

```
server {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    location /login {
        limit_req zone=sensitive burst=3 nodelay;
        fastcgi_pass php80;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass php80;
    }
}
```

**Careful:** Make sure you check that your "sensitive" `location` really matches with a higher priority. Something like `location /login.php` will probably be overridden by `location ~ \.php$`. In that case use `location = /login.php` instead.